# .netrc not being used in GitLab CI server

Tags: linux, security, gitlab-ci, .netrc

I'm trying to create a CI/CD pipeline, in particular an automated deployment job.

In the deploy stage I push my image to Heroku.

First, we need to authenticate with Heroku. This is done by placing the username and password in the `~/.netrc` file.

**This works when testing locally!**

However, has no affect when on the remote GitLab CI server (even though I `cat`ed it and can see the credentials in the `~/.netrc` file). I get an authorisation error when trying to push my image.

Why might this happen. Security reasons? On remote servers are `~/.netrc` files typically off limits? (i.e. does the system recognise a different `.netrc` file, not the standard one in the home directory?)

Thanks, really bugging me.

Comment: What versions of Git are you using on the local machine and the CI server?

Comment: What docker image are you using?